# How can I build Slickedit tags on command line?

Tags: tags, slickedit

I want to be able to generate slickedit tags on the commmand line, as soon as I sync a project from revision control - so via a script. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this topic http://community.slickedit.com/index.php?topic=253.0